# Oozie server start failed with "Invalid TimeZone: UTC" error

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, oozie

I am using Oozie 4.2.0 package(http://archive.apache.org/dist/oozie/4.2.0/). I built this Oozie package source and used it in windows and Linux machine over past 2 years. But, today I am getting the following error when starting oozie server (/bin/oozied.sh run) on my Linux machine which is newly created.

> Setting up oozie DB   setting CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xmx1024m"
>
> Validate DB Connection Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>           at org.apache.oozie.service.Services.(Services.java:114)
>           at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.getJdbcConf(OozieDBCLI.java:164)
>           at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.createConnection(OozieDBCLI.java:853)
>           at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.validateConnection(OozieDBCLI.java:861)
>           at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.createDB(OozieDBCLI.java:182)
>           at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.run(OozieDBCLI.java:126)
>           at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.main(OozieDBCLI.java:77) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid TimeZone: UTC
>           at org.apache.oozie.util.DateUtils.getTimeZone(DateUtils.java:146)
>           at org.apache.oozie.util.DateUtils.(DateUtils.java:44)
>           ... 7 more

When I am tracing this error in Oozie source file. The DateUtils.java file like below.
[image]

Here run time values for the following,

**tzId** = "UTC"

**tz** = sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]

**tz.getID()** = "GMT"

So, when checking the following condition in DateUtils.java. It always succeeds and throw IllegalArgumentException in my case.

```
if (!tz.getID().equals(tzId)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid TimeZone: " + tzId);
        }
```

My question is why my machine time zone is detecting timezone id "GMT" in java code. And why Apache oozie is checking this condition.
Please, help me to to start Oozie server. Thanks in Advance.

**Machine Environment Details:**

Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-116-generic x86_64)

locale - LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Timezone - Europe/Berlin